# How to edit a number of text files in a folder in C#?

Tags: c#

i have a number of text files in a folder (1800 files), all of which have the same formatting. They start like this:

"Station ABDEHGAH_ Lat = 30 27  Long = 51 2

1998 1 35050

1998 2 27800

1998 3 39500

1998 4 0"

i want to edit the first line of all of them to make it like this:
"ABDEHGAH 30.27 51.2"

What should i do?

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do from your description. Perhaps if you could clearly formulate what kind of transformation you want to perform on the text, then you will have a better idea of how to implement it.

Comment: How about to use Notepad++ "Replace in Files" function?

Comment: How about to use VIM? :-)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to just search and replace `_Lat =` with `""` and replace `Long =` with `""`  in all the files. It will involve three steps:

1. You will have to loop through all the files in the folder. Use  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx
2. Read the contents of each the file. Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ezwyzy7b.aspx
3. For each of the file, look for `_Lat =` and `Long =`  and replace it with `""`. Use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method. Note that you can use `String.Replace` only when `_Lat =` and `Long =` is consistent in all the files. What I mean is if in one of the file it is `Station ABDEHGAH_ Lat = 30 27 Long = 51 2` and in another it is something like `Station ABDEHGAH_ Lat = 30 27 Long=51 2`. Note the space. If not consistent you will have to use [RegEx.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) to look for patterns and replace them.

Answer (score 2):

This code works, try it:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\AnyFolder");   // You should include System.IO;

foreach (string s in files)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(s);
    text = text.Replace("old text", "new text");
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(s);
    writer.Write(text);
}
```

If this code will help you vote me.

Comment: For `1800` files of unkown content length, I don't think that is a good idea.

Comment: I don't have any another idea of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

[The full source for this approach here (Github)](https://github.com/brunolm/StackOverflow/blob/master/StackOverflow/How-to-edit-a-number-of-text-files-in-a-folder-in-c.cs)

I created two strings to hold the paths for the test

```
private readonly string sourceFiles = @"temp\source";
private readonly string outputFiles = @"temp\output";
```

And I created a [compiled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) [Regular Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx). This expression will:

- Ignore the first word
- Capture a word (A-Z only) and will ignore other characters such as `_`
- Capture a number after `Lat =` and if present another number separated by space
- Capture a number after `Long =` and if present another number separated by space

Regex:

```
private readonly Regex firstLineParser =
    new Regex(@"^[^ ]+ (?<StationName>[a-z]+).* Lat = (?<Lat>\d+(\s\d+)?) Long = (?<Long>\d+(\s\d+)?)$"
        , RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    );
```

It means I will have 3 groups and I can access them to manipulate the values.

So, to test the performance I am using a [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

```
public void Run()
{
    // performance test
    var timer = new Stopwatch();

    timer.Start();
```

[`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) will iterate through all elements using thread to run in parallel, this is a good idea when executing a task on a large number of files.

```
    Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(sourceFiles), f =>
    {
```

Now, for each element (full file path) we will create a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)

```
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(f))
        {
            // retrieves just the name of the file
            // after a few tests, it seems to be faster
            // than instantiating a FileInfo, not a big deal though
            var outfilename = f.Split('\\').Last();

            // reads the first line from the source file
            string line = sr.ReadLine();

            // run the expression to match the values
            // we want to separate
            var match = firstLineParser.Match(line);

            // now that we have the groups, we can format
            // the values the way we want
            line = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}"
                , match.Groups["StationName"].Value
                , match.Groups["Lat"].Value.Replace(" ", ".")
                , match.Groups["Long"].Value.Replace(" ", ".")
            );
```

The following will create a [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx)

```
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(outputFiles, outfilename)))
            {
                // we modified the first line, so lets write it
                sw.WriteLine(line);

                // now we just rewrite all remaining lines
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    sw.WriteLine(line);

                // and write to disk
                sw.Flush();
            }
        }
    });
```

And finally we stop the timer and show the elapsed time.

```
    timer.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.fff"));
}
```